# Why does Python mutliprocess.Process call in application start multiple instances of self?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pyinstaller, multiprocess

A GUI I've created uses multiprocess.Process function call to finish work quicker by using more than one process.

```
w1 = multiprocessing.Process(target = _process_worker.start)
```

When I run the GUI as a python script `gui.py` any I click the button that starts the workers everything works great, work is done quicker and no issues.

When I compile the python program into a window applications (using pyinstaller), clicking the same button causes the GUI to start multiple instances of itself; that is everytime the multiprocess call is made, the gui starts another gui application.

```
pyinstaller.ex --onefile --windowed --icon=guiicon.ico gui.py
```

Does anyone know how I can have the process just do the work instead of opening multiple instances of itself? Why is it doing this in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*In using the `multiprocessing` module, you must call*

```
multiprocessing.freeze_support()
```

*straight after the `if __name__ == '__main__':` line of the main module.*

*Please read the Python library manual about multiprocessing.freeze_support for more information.*

**Reference**: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-Multiprocessing